# Using Eclipse To Study Large Code Base, and Trace Method Calls

Tags: eclipse, debugging, trace

I am starting to work with a very large code base (a large webapp), and want to be able to see the method calls in order to understand how the requests are served.  So, I want to use Eclipse to trace method calls for any request that comes in.  I'm not sure, but I think that the best way of doing this is through remote debugger; so, I have already created a remote debugger.  Now, my question is the following:

1. How can I configure the debugger such that as soon as a request comes in, the debugger would pause, and allow me to control its step through.
2. Is there a better way of tracing method calls (for the purpose of studying the code), or using a debugger is really the best method?

Comment: Why not local debugging?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do debugging of webapps using Eclipse's local debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Use the trace module, and exclude framework or other uninteresting directories.

```
-m trace --file=/tmp/trace.log -t --ignore-dir=/home/unifield-server
```

You can then tail the trace file as it runs.

```
$ tail -f trace.log
```

You can also periodically clear it or append a marker for later analysis

```
$ echo > trace.log
$ echo 'about to press save button' >> trace.log
```